# How to find the list of dynamic IP Addresses for the outbound connection to Twilio?

Tags: twilio

Our firewall restricts outbound network connections. Hence we need to know the list of IP addresses to which we need to open up the port for outbound network connections that connects to Twilio for the REST API for sending sms. 
How to find out what are the list of IP addresses that twilio uses for outbound connections so that we can open those in our firewall?

As per the Twilio docs it says we need to open up for https://api.twilio.com.
Unfortunately our firewall needs to define a list of IP addresses instead of a URL and it looks like the IP Addresses keep changing and is not static. 
Does the following hold good for outbound connections from Twilio for Messages via their REST API?

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1701

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

[From the FAQ article on this topic](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/which-ip-addresses-will-twilios-requests-come-from):

> Twilio makes HTTP requests to your server to fetch your app’s [TwiML instructions](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/your_response). Some users prefer to know which IP address the request from Twilio is coming from in order to open up specific ports in a firewall. However, due to the fluid nature of our cloud architecture, we don’t have a set range of IPs that requests are sent from or know in advance what they will be.
>
> Because Twilio’s requests will be coming from different IP addresses, we instead recommend that you validate that a request came from Twilio by other means. [Please see our documentation on securing your application for more details](http://www.twilio.com/docs/security).
>
> If the inability to have a request come from a static IP address is a serious concern, [please contact our sales department to discuss other options which might be available](https://www.twilio.com/help/sales).

Comment: I am looking for outbound connections "TO" twilio and not for inbound connections. Our firewall looks at IP Addresses while making connection to https://api.twilio.com. It looks like the Amazon AWS or google keeps changing the IP Addresses and so when we try to send out an sms we are not able to connect to twilio's API.

Comment: The same dynamics apply to IP addresses for incoming requests - we can't guarantee ahead of time which IP addresses will service API requests. I would offer the same advice as the FAQ, to contact Twilio and describe your needs, and see if a special accommodation can be made.